# How much additional disk space does tar require

Tags: unix, filesystems, tar

I am moving a `tar.gz` archive between servers and had to note that when extracting the archive a large amount of additional disk space is used. My original data size is 12G, 7.8G compressed and consumes an excess of 57G. I am copying from a `zfs` file-system to an `ext4`. Does anyone know if this issue is related to tar or to the file-systems used?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it appears the `zfs` file-system had **compression** enabled, which reduced the size of the archive by approximately **5 times**. Zfs uses transparent compression (LZJB) and you can find more details [here](http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=983).